# Calculus II, or Calculus 2, or Calculus Two, is there a preference?

Tags: numbers

Judging from the way Super Bowls are named I guess "Calculus II" is the right one. But what is the rule if there is any?

Comment: "II", "2", and "two" are different ways of saying the same thing, so all three are interchangeable. On books they often use "II" I assume this is due to the aesthetic of using roman numerals for titles (same reason the super bowl uses this, "LVII" just looks more aesthetic than "57"). Most native AmE speakers use "2" in my experience just because it is the shortest to type. "I am taking calculus 2 next semester," but it would not be uncommon to see "calculus II" either, just because it is so common on the text books people tend to use it.

Comment: I've seen both II and 2; it may depend on the speaker/writer or the school that's offering the course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a unified stylistic requirement for academic courses. The [Associated Press recommends](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/subject_specific_writing/journalism_and_journalistic_writing/ap_style.html) roman numerals for wars or people, like "George III" and "World War II." A "second level" of a subject, like "Calculus II" might follow this pattern, though often courses get "catalog numbers" like "Humanities 101" or even longer unique numbers. For simplicity, numbers over 10 tend to be given in arabic numerals, since we're not in the habit of using large roman numerals.

There are plenty of exceptions. The Super Bowl follows its own tradition. The sequel to the movie *Rocky* is officially titled *Rocky II*. But the sequel to *Toy Story* is *Toy Story 2*.